# apple review policy toward Query developed apps

Tags: ios, iphone, jquery-mobile, uiwebview

will apple allow me to publish an app that doesn't include any offline functionality ?

I developed an application using jQuery-mobile and i'm showing it in UIWebView , i offer the user the following functionalities 
1.downloading video / audio / images 
2. media streaming

and other content .

Comment: If your app could be a website it probably won't make it to the app store. Have a look at the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html). But we are talking about apple. Each reviewer has a different opinion. And they usually change their opinion twice a day. In such edge-cases nobody can say for sure.

Comment: thnx Matthias, the app provide media content and it certainly cant be a website. i read the App store Review GuidLines and i'm following them during development but the document doesn't say anything about apps that are unavailable offline !

Comment: Why don't you ask Apple? Or read their guidelines? Or submit it and see what they say? Apple are the only ones who know what Apple will allow.

Answer (score 0):

> Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

If your app isn’t useful it may be rejected. That’s between you and Apple, though.